# Calculate the closest perpendicular point between a static line and a movable line

Tags: javascript, geometry

### Description

Given is a blue line, which can be placed as pleased and is movable by mouse.
By moving the line a gradient line (here in hotpink) is drawn from the original position. Now this line has the following requirements:

Assuming the left edge of the blue line being point 1 (red circle) and
assuming the left edge of the original position of the blue line being point 2 (lime circle)
assuming the right side of the blue line being point 3 (green circle)
the angle from point 1 needs to be either 90 or -90 degress to point2/point3.

*I believe the term for this is: the gradient hotpink line and the blue line are to be perpendicular.*
**The direction of the blue line is not to change, only its position!**

[image: Sample]

### My issue

By moving the blue line I am able to calculate the degree to its original position and to draw the gradient hotpink line. Yet I am unable to calculate the closest point from the blue line which would make the gradient hotpink line perpendicular to both the original blue line and the new position of the blue line. If someone can point me to correct formula or proper term for this problem, I would be grateful.

### Visual example (**scraped** code parts)

Followed is a quick example which I **scraped** together. One can move the blue line yet I can not force point 1 to keep a certain 90/-90 degree angle to point2/point3.

```js
//REM: Current moving element
var _currentElement = null;

//REM: Drawing for quicker access
var _Drawing = null;

//REM: Starting the drag
function _onDown(event){
  if(event.target && event.target.tagName === 'line'){
    let tMatrix = _getMatrix(event.target);
    
    _currentElement = {
      Element: event.target,
      startX: event.clientX,
      startY: event.clientY,
      startE: tMatrix.e,
      startF: tMatrix.f,
      X1: Number(event.target.getAttribute('x1')),
      Y1: Number(event.target.getAttribute('y1')),
      X2: Number(event.target.getAttribute('x2')),
      Y2: Number(event.target.getAttribute('y2')),
      Ratio: 0.4
    }
  }
}

//REM: Dragging
function _onMove(event){
  if(_currentElement){
    _currentElement.endE = _currentElement.startE + ((event.clientX - _currentElement.startX) * _currentElement.Ratio);
    _currentElement.endF = _currentElement.startF + ((event.clientY - _currentElement.startY) * _currentElement.Ratio);

    console.log(
      'Angle (3)',
      _getAngleBetweenThreePoints(
        {x: _currentElement.X1 + _currentElement.endE, y: _currentElement.Y1 + _currentElement.endF},
        {x: _currentElement.X1, y: _currentElement.Y1},
        {x: _currentElement.X2 + _currentElement.endE, y: _currentElement.Y2 + _currentElement.endF}
      )
    );

    _setMatrix(_currentElement.Element, 1, 0, 0, 1, _currentElement.endE, _currentElement.endF)
  }
}

//REM: Ending the drag
function _onUp(){
  _currentElement = null
}

//REM: Returns the elements matrix
function _getMatrix(element){
  if(element){
    return element.transform.baseVal.numberOfItems ?
    element.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).matrix :
    element.transform.baseVal.appendItem(_Drawing.createSVGTransform()).matrix
  }
}

//REM: Sets the elements matrix
function _setMatrix(element, a, b, c, d, e, f){
  if(element){
    let tMatrix = _getMatrix(element);
    if(tMatrix){
      tMatrix.a = (typeof a === 'number') ? a : tMatrix.a;
      tMatrix.b = (typeof b === 'number') ? b : tMatrix.b;
      tMatrix.c = (typeof c === 'number') ? c : tMatrix.c;
      tMatrix.d = (typeof d === 'number') ? d : tMatrix.d;
      tMatrix.e = (typeof e === 'number') ? e : tMatrix.e;
      tMatrix.f = (typeof f === 'number') ? f : tMatrix.f;

      element.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).setMatrix(tMatrix)
    }
  }
}

//REM: Transforms client-coords to svg-coords
function _getSVGCoords(clientX, clientY){
    var tCTM = _Drawing.getScreenCTM();
    return tCTM ? {x: (clientX - tCTM.e) / tCTM.a, y: (clientY - tCTM.f ) / tCTM.d} : {x: clientX, y: clientY}
}

//REM: Returns angle from p1 to p2 and p3
function _getAngleBetweenThreePoints(p1, p2, p3){
  let tAngle = 0;

  if(p1 && p2 && p3){
    let tTemplate = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
    tTemplate.setAttribute('r', 1);
    
    let tC1 = _Drawing.appendChild(tTemplate.cloneNode(false));
    tC1.setAttribute('fill', 'red');
    tC1.setAttribute('cx', p1.x);
    tC1.setAttribute('cy', p1.y);
    
    let tC2 = _Drawing.appendChild(tTemplate.cloneNode(false));
    tC2.setAttribute('fill', 'lime');
    tC2.setAttribute('cx', p2.x);
    tC2.setAttribute('cy', p2.y);
    
    let tC3 = _Drawing.appendChild(tTemplate.cloneNode(false));
    tC3.setAttribute('fill', 'green');
    tC3.setAttribute('cx', p3.x);
    tC3.setAttribute('cy', p3.y);
    
    let tLine = document.getElementById('line1');
    if(!tLine){
      tLine = _Drawing.appendChild(document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line'));
      tLine.id = 'line1';
      tLine.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', '5,5')
    };
    
    tLine.setAttribute('x1', p1.x);
    tLine.setAttribute('y1', p1.y);
    tLine.setAttribute('x2', p2.x);
    tLine.setAttribute('y2', p2.y);

    tAngle = (Math.atan2(p3.y - p1.y, p3.x - p1.x) - Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x)) * 180 / Math.PI
  }

  return tAngle
};

//REM: Assiging events
window.onload = function(){
  _Drawing = document.querySelector('svg');

  document.body.addEventListener('mousedown', _onDown, false);
  document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', _onMove, false);
  document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', _onUp, false);
  document.body.addEventListener('mouseleave', _onUp, false)
};
```

```css
line,
circle{
  pointer-events: none;
  stroke-width: 1
}

#movable{
  pointer-events: all;
  stroke-width: 10
}

#line1{
  stroke: hotpink
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox = '0 0 300 300'>
  <line x1 = '50' y1 = '50' x2 = '160' y2 = '110' stroke = 'blue' id = 'movable'></line>
</svg>
```

### Expected result

By moving the blue line I draw a gradient hotpink line. That gradient line has to be perpendicular to the original position of the blue line as well as the new position of the blue line. The direction of the blue line itself may not change, just its position. If the line would be horizontal, merely straight up and straight down would be allowed. If the line was vertical, merely straight left and right would be allowed. If the line is diagonal, merely movements which are straight in the alignment of that line would be allowed (like a railway). So for example by having my diagonal blue line and moving straight upwards, I want to calculate the closest position from the left edge which would make the gradient hotpink line perpendicular to both the original position of the blue line and the new position of the blue line.

It is a behaviour very similar to [Adobe PDF Measuring Tool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQUWNU9p5dg).

Comment: 1. Do you want to restrict the movement of that blue line (only moving perpendicular to itself)? Or do you want to draw the gradient perpendicular? 2. When you have two vectors, they are orthogonal, if their dot product is zero. That could help.

Comment: @Josef Wittmann: I want to restrict the movement of the blue line, so that the pink line is always perpendicular. So kinda both. Adobe PDF offers the same funtionality, which is there called *Distance tool* together with [Snap To Endpoints](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5sJH1CGPLY&t=135). I will check out your hint. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a class that gives you the x,y of where the blue line needs to be placed.

```
class cTracker {
constructor(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    x1 = parseInt(x1);
    y1 = parseInt(y1);
    x2 = parseInt(x2);
    y2 = parseInt(y2);
    
    const extendLine = 10000;
    
    let blueLineRadian = Math.atan2(x1 - x2, y1 - y2);
    this.m_blueLineRadian = blueLineRadian;
    
    
    let magentaLineRadian = blueLineRadian + (Math.PI / 2);
    
    this.m_blueLineCos = Math.cos(blueLineRadian) * extendLine;
    this.m_blueLineSin = Math.sin(blueLineRadian) * extendLine;
    
    this.m_magentaLineX1 = x1 + Math.sin(magentaLineRadian) * extendLine;
    this.m_magentaLineY1 = y1 + Math.cos(magentaLineRadian) * extendLine;
    
    this.m_magentaLineX2 = x1 + Math.sin(magentaLineRadian + Math.PI) * extendLine;
    this.m_magentaLineY2 = y1 + Math.cos(magentaLineRadian + Math.PI) * extendLine;
    
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
getCursorPosition(x, y) {
    this.m_x1 = x - this.m_blueLineSin;
    this.m_y1 = y - this.m_blueLineCos;
    this.m_x2 = x + this.m_blueLineSin;
    this.m_y2 = y + this.m_blueLineCos;

        
    return this.intersect(this.m_magentaLineX1, this.m_magentaLineY1, this.m_magentaLineX2, this.m_magentaLineY2, this.m_x1, this.m_y1, this.m_x2, this.m_y2);
}

                                              
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  //
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  intersect(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4) {
      
      var denominator = ((y4 - y3) * (x2 - x1)) - ((x4 - x3) * (y2 - y1));
      
      var a                                   = y1 - y3;
      var b                                   = x1 - x3;
      var numerator1                          = ((x4 - x3) * a) - ((y4 - y3) * b);
      var numerator2                          = ((x2 - x1) * a) - ((y2 - y1) * b);
      a                                       = numerator1 / denominator;
      
      return {m_x : x1 + (a * (x2 - x1)), m_y : y1 + (a * (y2 - y1))};
  }
 }
```

To use it, create an instant with x1, y1, x2, y2 of the blue line

```
let movableLine = document.getElementById('movable');
    
let x1 = parseInt(movableLine.getAttribute("x1"));
let y1 = parseInt(movableLine.getAttribute("y1"));
let x2 = parseInt(movableLine.getAttribute("x2"));
let y2 = parseInt(movableLine.getAttribute("y2"));

this.m_tracker = new cTracker(x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

To get the X,Y on where to place the blue line you simply do the following...

```
let xySVG = this._getSVGCoords(event.clientX, event.clientY);         
let xy = this.m_tracker.getCursorPosition(xySVG.x, xySVG.y);

console.log(xy); // This is where the blue line needs to be placed...
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/syxfv63z/2/

Comment: This is still required in order to calculate the 90 degrees angle like you wanted. What you need to do is to keep the angle between p1 & p2 constant but the length of the line is allowed to change. The angle p2 & p3 will remain a static line like you want as shown in the link you provided. I take it you want the formula to restrict the angle p1 & p2 ?

Comment: Try this fiddle... https://jsfiddle.net/9qgfs6k4/6/ is this what you are after? The way the mouse moves in relation to the line being dragged is currently not ideal due to how it calculates the mouse position and the ratio you've added isn't helping. I have some code that does this correctly and I'll do an update once you've confirmed this is how you wanted it to work.

Comment: `x1 == x2 || y1 == y2 ? 0 : Math.tan(-radians)` is probably incorrect for the `y1 == y2` case. It restricts the movements to horizontal, yet should restrict the movemets to vertical.

Comment: This is because tan(pi / 2) returns a massive number for infinity which is why those conditions exists and why you get a big jump. The trick is to swap event.clientX with event.clientY when x1 == x2 and it'll somewhat work but that doesn't really solve your mouse tracking accuracy problem correctly that I mentioned. I didn't finish this off because I just wanted to know if I was on the right lines of what you were after before continuing and you gave the impression that you've solved the mouse movement. I will make an update shortly.

Comment: I've updated it and it now work differently to what I previously posted. I've stripped out most of your code as bare minimum so you can figure out what is different. I've also added debug visuals to get an idea of what is happening. This will handle vertical and horizontal lines correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I misunderstood what you meant by *mouse tracking*. I have an own method to convert client-coordinates to svg-coordinates, due to `_getSVGCoords()` causing performance issues by rapid movements on ancient browsers. I implemented the logic in my project (sadly as ES5) and it works great. Having alot of fun with this. Thanks again. PS: Removed some old comments.

Answer (score 1):

To get the movement perpendicular to the blue line, do the following:

1. Get the vector of the blue lines orientation.
2. Rotate it 90 deg (its perpendicular to its surface).
3. Normalize it, e.g. make its length equal `1` (call it `n`).
4. Now get the movement vector of the mouse (`current - start`, call it `m`).
5. Now calculate `n * dot(n,m)`. That is your movement vector in `n` direction.

Comment: Thanks, this helped my out to create the gradient line correctly. Johns answer kinda includes all I need so that is the one I accepted in the end.